# Check if part of a string is in part of a string

Tags: python, list, substring, any

```
string_to_check = "Amazon.com is a company"
listtocheck = ["Amazon.com", "Apple"]

res = any((x:=rea.lower()) in string_to_check.lower() for rea in listtocheck)
if(res == True):
   print(x)
```

This code prints `amazon.com`. How can I also get `amazon.com` as a return when `listtocheck` does not contain exactly `"amazon.com"`? Let's say it contains `"amazon"`. Now there is no output because the ".com" is missing.

Can I say somehow that for example 4 characters of the `listtocheck` item (amaz, .com, mazo) has to match with the string to check? So it's like get me a return if ..% of the `listtocheck` item is matching with the `stringtocheck`.

Comment: "amazon" should still match. `in` tests if the substring exists, not if the "word" exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: slice `rea.lower())[:4]`

```
string_to_check = "Amazon.com is a company"
listtocheck = ["Amazon", "Apple"]

res = any((x:=rea.lower())[:4] in string_to_check.lower() for rea in
          listtocheck)
if(res == True):
   print(x)
```